# How to set AlertDialog custom title top margin and remove unwanted Padding?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I am stuck with a `margin` and `padding` issue of a title of `AlertDialog.Builder`,  what i am doing is i want the title in `center` so i am using `setCustomTitle` i am able to do so but stuck with margin and padding of it. I don't want unwanted padding which is showing and also i want to set some top margin to title, i am using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` but it has no effect. please suggest what to do to handle it.thanks

Code :

```
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
TextView title = new TextView(context);
title.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
title.setLayoutParams(lp);
title.setText("Dialog");
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
dialog.setCustomTitle(title);
dialog.setMessage("Dialog box with custom title view ");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Result :[image]

Comment: Looks good ! I don't see any problem in padding.U can **center** the text if u want in `dialog` `setContentView()` using gravity concept !

Comment: @utkarshdubey i dont want much padding between dialog title and dialog message which is coming asa result by default

Answer (score 8):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black));
title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
title.setPadding(0,30,0,0);
title.setLayoutParams(lp);
title.setText("Dialog");
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
dialog.setCustomTitle(title);
dialog.setMessage("Dialog box with custom title view ");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Replace this code it will work

Comment: thanks `setPadding`  workes but how to remove padding between dialog's title and message any idea ?

Comment: @KapilRajput try to set custom dialog instead of Alert Dialog it will give more customization

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid setting up all this methods to your AlertDialog by using DialogFragment. Just use `getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in `onCreateView` method and make your own custom view for the dialog in the way you create a common fragment. It's a better way to make proper dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use DialogFragment to show custom layout as alert Dialog its very easy and we can customize our dialog as per requirement..for more detail about it :  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Below is the layout as per your requirement, You can use the below xml layout to show your custom layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="My Dialog"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="My Dialog Box Description !"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```